# Vue.js 2 - How to call one this.$root.$on mounted function to another?

Tags: vue.js

Hope you all are having a good day!

I have a really simple question, does anyone know, how to call punchHealth() to healHealth() ?

```
  mounted() {
    this.$root.$on('punchHealth', () => {
      this.healthOne -= Math.floor(Math.random() * (20 - 10)) + 10;
      this.healthTwo -= Math.floor(Math.random() * (20 - 10)) + 10;
    })
    this.$root.$on('doublePunchHealth', () => {
      this.healthOne -= Math.floor(Math.random() * (30 - 20)) + 20;
      this.healthTwo -= Math.floor(Math.random() * (30 - 20)) + 20;
    }),
    this.$root.$on('healHealth', () => {
      // ...
    })
  }
```

Many thanks!

Comment: are you looking for `this.$root.$emit('punchHealth')`?

Comment: @thanksd that is exactly what I was looking for, thanks man! So that is the way how to call these kinds of functions within mounted()? Cool!